Procedure for printing numbers doesn't work
I'm working with TASM (in DosBOX emulator).
I'm a beginner and I don't know much yet.
Below is my full code. The problem is that it prints out not just expected output (25 + 10 = 35 and 25 - 10 = 15) but also some rubbish and the program freezes:


SSEG    segment stack   
        db 256 dup(0)
SSEG    ends

DSEG    segment         
   num1 dw 25
   num2 dw 10
   new_line db 0dh,0ah,'$'
   msg_add db '25 + 10 = ','$'
   msg_sub db '25 - 10 = ','$'
DSEG    ends

CSEG    segment         
        assume cs:CSEG,ds:DSEG,ss:SSEG
    

begin:
    
    
    mov ax, DSEG    
    mov ds, ax      
    
    ; ADD
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset msg_add
    int 21h
    mov ax, num1
    mov bx, num2
    add ax, bx

    mov ax, ax
    call print_number

    
    ; SUB
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset msg_sub
    int 21h
    mov ax, num1
    mov bx, num2
    sub ax, bx

    mov ax, ax
    call print_number

    print_number proc

        mov si,10
        mov cx,0
    a:
        mov dx,0
        div si
        add dx,'0'
        push dx
        inc cx
        cmp ax,0
        jnz a
    aa:
        pop dx
        mov ah,02h
        int 21h
        loop aa
    
        mov ah, 09h
        mov dx, offset new_line
        int 21h
        
        
        
        ret
    print_number endp

    mov ah,4ch      
    int 21h         
    
    
CSEG    ends        
end begin           


I tried different approaches of passing arguments into the function. To minmize the code I list only ADD (it's the same logic with SUB)

by stack

    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset msg_add
    int 21h
    mov ax, num1
    mov bx, num2
    add ax, bx
    push ax
    call print_number

I tried both popping and pushing of ax register in print_number
popping:
print_number proc
        pop ax
        mov si,10
        mov cx,0
    a:
        mov dx,0
        div si
        add dx,'0'
        push dx
        inc cx
        cmp ax,0
        jnz a
    aa:
        pop dx
        mov ah,02h
        int 21h
        loop aa
    
        mov ah, 09h
        mov dx, offset new_line
        int 21h
    
        
        ret
    print_number endp


pushing:
print_number proc
        push ax
        mov si,10
        mov cx,0
    a:
        mov dx,0
        div si
        add dx,'0'
        push dx
        inc cx
        cmp ax,0
        jnz a
    aa:
        pop dx
        mov ah,02h
        int 21h
        loop aa
    
        mov ah, 09h
        mov dx, offset new_line
        int 21h

        
        ret
    print_number endp


By registers (not sure if I did it right)

It's as in the first code of the question
; ADD
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset msg_add
    int 21h
    mov ax, num1
    mov bx, num2
    add ax, bx

    mov ax, ax
    call print_number

print_number proc

        mov si,10
        mov cx,0
    a:
        mov dx,0
        div si
        add dx,'0'
        push dx
        inc cx
        cmp ax,0
        jnz a
    aa:
        pop dx
        mov ah,02h
        int 21h
        loop aa

        mov ah, 09h
        mov dx, offset new_line
        int 21h



        ret
    print_number endp


But every code doesn't work properly.
I expect just two following lines:
25 + 10 = 35
25 - 10 = 15
With every approach it also prints out rubbish and the program freezes.
How can I fix that?

Try to move instructions: mov ah,4ch, int 21h before print_number proc. This service properly ends program and returns control to the system. In your case code runs through print_number proc so that's why you see mess on the screen.

Looks like you have no way to get out of the aa:...loop aa loop so it's just going to print stuff forever

@PeterHull On entry to print_number cx = 0, in a: cx is incremented two times and in aa: loop aa decrements cx.

Sorry you're right, I am very rusty on this. But does the int21 corrupt the value of cx, i.e. do you need to push/pop it around the int21?

@PeterHull Intel manual says that in real-mode int only pushes flags,cs and ip. DOS API specifies what registers are used in every function. Here 02h, 09h and 4ch don't need cx and also after interrupt cx is preserved. Well, my debugger says so.

@nassau now I've re-read your first comment and the code (got confused by the various code blocks some of which scroll!) you were right all along


Procedure for printing numbers doesn't work


mov ax, ax
call print_number
                   <--- Here program should end
print_number proc
  mov si,10


The procedure for printing numbers works fine, but immediately after printing the line 25 - 10 = 15, the program should have terminated. Because the mention of proc does not create a barrier for the CPU, instead the execution simply continued on the following lines where firstly a 'random' number got printed and then the real problems began because the ret instruction that ends the print_number procedure had no sensible return address on the stack. That's the kind of thing that can freeze a program...
Like Nassau wrote in a comment the solution is:
call print_number
mov  ax, 4C00h
int  21h             ; DOS.Terminate
; -------------------
; IN (ax)
print_number proc
  mov  si, 10

Your attempts at solving the issue

push ax               ; (35)
call print_number
...
print_number proc
  pop  ax
  mov  si, 10
  ...
  ret


This can't work because the pop ax will not retrieve the number (35), but rather the return address that the call instruction placed on the stack. Later, the ret instruction will interpret (35) as an address to return to, but, as you understand, it is not an address at all.

push ax
call print_number
...
print_number proc
  push ax
  mov  si, 10
  ...
  ret


This can't work because the second push ax will force the ret instruction to return to an incorrect address. Moreover both the pushed argument and the correct return address remain on the stack, and so stack overflow is to be expected at some time in the future.

mov  ax, ax
call print_number
...
print_number proc
  mov  si, 10


This is correct but the mov ax, ax instruction doesn't do anything useful. It just wastes 2 bytes and a small amount of time.
